# remove factor level from dataframe

Tags: r, statistics, dataset, categories, kaggle

I downloaded the titanic train dataset from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data) :

My code is :

```
df = read.csv('titanic.csv', header=TRUE)
df$Pclass = as.factor(df$Pclass)
df$Survived = as.factor(df$Survived)
df = df[,c(2,3,5,6,12)]
df = na.omit(df)
rownames(df) <- 1:nrow(df)
df$Age[df$Age <= 18] = "child"
df$Age[(df$Age > 18) & (df$Age <= 60) & (df$Age != "child")] = "adult"
df$Age[(df$Age != "child") & (df$Age != "adult")] = "senior"
df$Age = as.factor(df$Age)
summary(df)
```

At this point the result of summary is :

```
 Survived Pclass      Sex          Age      Embarked
 0:424    1:186   female:261   adult :553    :  2   
 1:290    2:173   male  :453   child :139   C:130   
          3:355                senior: 22   Q: 28   
                                            S:554
```

My problem is Embarked variable:

```
barplot(table(df$Embarked), xlab="Port of Embarkment", ylab="Frequency", main="Histograma de la variable \n Embarked")
```

[barplot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIH8t.jpg)

The levels of Embarked

```
> levels(df$Embarked)
[1] ""  "C" "Q" "S"
```

Here is my problem, this first level : "" (empty) , I can't find a way to remove it. I've been testing several ways I found in stackoverflow without being able to solve my problem.

Comment: Add a ```na.strings``` argument to ```read.csv```, so that you're first line is ```df = read.csv('titanic.csv', na.strings = "")```.  Also, you don't need the ```header = TRUE``` argument; that is the default for ```read.csv```

Answer (score 1):

After removing the lines with empty values for Embarked, refactorize:

```
df <- df[df$Embarked!="",]
df$Embarked <- factor(df$Embarked)
barplot(table(df$Embarked), xlab="Port of Embarkment", 
        ylab="Frequency", main="Histograma de la variable \n Embarked")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could also use `droplevels`:

```
df <- droplevels(df)
```

New levels of `Embarked`:

```
> levels(df$Embarked)
[1] "C" "Q" "S"
```

The advantage of this approach it will drop all unused levels from a factor. You can also drop all unused levels from factors in a whole data frame.